# When use Cmake to compile LZO,it notes that can't find any instance of VS

Tags: c++, cmake

I have installed VS2015 (win64) and I wanna use Cmake to compile LZO to generate a VS project,but the Cmake show this:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:51 (project):
  Generator
    Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64
  could not find any instance of Visual Studio.
```

I think the problem may come from the Cmakelist.txt document,but I don't know how to fix it...
The 51 row of CmakeList.txt file is:

```
if(",${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}," STREQUAL ",${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR},")
    message(FATAL_ERROR "ERROR: In-source builds are not allowed.")
endif()

if(NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)
    set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "Release" CACHE STRING "" FORCE)
endif()

project(lzo VERSION 2.10 LANGUAGES C++)
```

Comment: If you think the error is in your `CMakeLists.txt` file, how would we be able to find it and help you if you don't show it to us? Also, how do you invoke `cmake`? Please edit your question to include that information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Generator Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64*** is the wrong generator for Visual Studio 2015. You need `Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64` if you have any trouble with that execute cmake-gui from a Visual Studio 2015 x64 command prompt so you have the compiler environment variables setup.

Comment: you're right,I should choose Visual Studio 14 Win64,but it get more complecated,Cmake shows:CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file: CMakeDetermineC++Compiler.cmake
CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file: E:/cmake_test/CMakeFiles/3.11.0-rc3/CMakeC++Compiler.cmake
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:51 (project):
  No CMAKE_C++_COMPILER could be found.
CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file: CMakeC++Information.cmake

Comment: I would delete your build folder for this project and downgrade CMake to the latest released version 3.10.2. Install that using the installer from here: https://cmake.org/download . CMake should not be installed  in E:/cmake_test. The error says that parts of CMake are missing.

Comment: I installed Cmake in C disk by the default set ,the dir of source code is E:/LZO/lzo-2.10,the dir to build  the binaries is E:/cmake_test ,the version of  Cmake is 3.11.0,I will try another version

Comment: I get the reason now,it's because of the source code,there must be some bugs in the original files of LZO in version 2.10.When I use version 2.08 to create VS project,it works!

Answer (score 0):

When I used LZO of version 2.08,the errors disappeared!So I think there must be some bugs in the original files of LZO in version 2.10.